# Why map remove every attributes to my object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I start to learn ruby on rails and I want to add an attribute to each object so I used map to do this, here is what I have :

I've add this to my model : `attr_accessor :dettes`

```
@depenses = Depense.where(user_id: @user.id)
@depenses = @depenses.map {
    |d|
  d.dettes =  value
}
```

But this remove every attribute of the objects to set only the new attributes, I tried with `each`

```
@depenses.each do |d|
  d.dettes =  "value"
end
```

But this didn't worked too, my new attribute isn't set

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

It is your assignment that is probably messing things up...

```
@depenses = @depenses.map {
^^^            ^^^
new          old
```

you are overwriting the old value of `@depenses` with what is being returned by the `map`. This new version will contain only the attributes that were used in the map... and you have just destroyed the old value and replaced it with this value.

`each` is definitely the way to go (as per the other answer)... you say you "tried `each`" - but we'd like to see what code you literally actually tried so we can help you debug it.

As to your `attr_accessor`... you don't need it if this is an actual `attribute` - did you write a migration to add the column `dettes` to your `depenses` table? if so - then never put `attr_accessor` into your model for one of those - it tends to mess things up like this :)

If you remove that line - things should start working again (or at least unveil the next bug) :D

Comment: I've add this to my model : `attr_accessor :dettes` and here is how I get my variable `@depenses = Depense.where(user_id: @user.id)` Also I've edited my question, thanks

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer for you - the problem is probably the `attr_accessor` thing. I've seen that before as a bug - it messes up assignments for real attributes.